# How to serialize and deserialize a kdtree in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, kdtree

I  have a kdtree whose nodes consist of the following fields:
public static class Node implements Serializable
    {

```
    public int discriminator;
    public double value; 

    public Node leftChild;
    public Node rightChild;
    public DataPoint object;
    }
```

where DataPoint definition:

public static class DataPoint implements Serializable
     {
         public Comparable X;
         public Comparable Y;
         public Comparable Z;

```
     public double latitude;
     public double longitude;

     public ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     }
```

I want to serialize the tree, store in a file and deserialize while answering range queries. My understanding of this concept od serialization is not fine. From whatever I gathered,I have written the following functions, which is not working. Can anybody help?

```
 public static void serialize(final OutputStream out, kdtrees.Node node) throws IOException
 {
        if( node == null ) 
        {
            //out.write( "()".getBytes() );
            //write to an output leaf file
            out.write("#".getBytes());

        } 
        else 
        {
            //out.write( "(".getBytes() );
            ((ObjectOutputStream) out).writeObject(node);
            serialize( out, node.leftChild );
            serialize( out, node.rightChild );
            //out.write( ")".getBytes( ) );
        }
    }


 public static kdtrees.Node deserialize(final ObjectInputStream reader) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
 {

                  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(reader.readObject().toString()); 
                  String curToken = st.nextToken().toString();
                  while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                  { 
                      if(curToken.equals("#".trim()))
                          return null;


                      kdtrees.Node e = (kdtrees.Node)reader.readObject();

                       e.leftChild = deserialize(reader);
                       e.rightChild = deserialize(reader);

                    return e;

                  }
               return null;   


    }
```

Comment: "no working" isn't helpful.  Please be much more specific.

Comment: It's compiling fine, but the tree is not getting reconstructed. It's returning null.

Answer (score 1):

Casting an arbitrary `OutputStream` to an `ObjectOutputStream` is just going to fail.  Instead, use `new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)` to create a wrapper around the `OutputStream`, and the same thing for the `InputStream`s.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? Sorry I am new to Java.

Comment: Um.  Instead of `((ObjectOutputStream) out), write `new ObjectOutputStream(out)`.  Same goes for the input streams.  Also, there's no need to call `serialize(out, node.leftChild)` or `serialize(out, node.rightChild)`; the children will get automatically serialized with the parent node.